# I can't delete a WhatsApp Message Template?

Tags: facebook, whatsapp

I am trying to delete some WhatsApp Message Templates from inside the WhatsAPP manager interface on the Meta (Facebook) Devlopers website and I get an error that they can not be deleted. Try again later. With no other explanation.

Comment: That sounds a Meta bug. And you should use their bug tracker.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a programming question.